# local variable referenced before assignment in python OOP program

Tags: python, class, oop

I understand what this error means, but I don't understand why I am getting it. It happens near the bottom of the code, line 76 for example but each time I reference the variable it happens. I called the instances of the class bank account and then set the one the user chooses equal to account, but when I try to use dot notation to access the method on account (for example `print("Current balance is: ", account.deposit(pin,amount))`) it says the local variable account is referenced before assignment

```
class BankAccount: #creates a bank account class
    def __init__(self, pin): #initializes a constructor method with two parameters, self and pin
        self._balance = 0 #initializes balance at 0
        self._pin = pin #sets pin as the pin parameter
        
    def deposit(self, pin, amount): #creates deposit method with three parameters. Self, pin and amount
        if pin != self._pin: #if pin parameter doesnt match initialized pin
            print("Wrong pin") 
        if amount > 3000: #if the amount is more than 3000
            check = int(input("Please enter pin again to deposit large amount: ")) #requests pin again for large amount
            if check != self._pin: #if the user enters the wrong pin the second time
                print("Pin is incorrect. Transaction cancelled.")
            elif check == self._pin: #if user enters correct pin
                self._balance += amount #add amount to current balance
                return self._balance #return balance
                
        elif amount <= 3000 and amount>0: #if the amount is less or equal to 30000
            self._balance += amount #add amount to current balance
            return self._balance  #return balance         
        else:
            print("invalid input") #if user enters anything else its invalid
            
    def withdraw(self, pin, amount): #creates withdraw method with three parameters; self, pin and amount
        
        if pin != self._pin: #if user enters wrong pin
            print("Wrong pin. Try  Again")
            return              
        if amount > self._balance: #if trying to withdraw more than in account
            print("You are attemtping to withdraw more than is in your account")
            
        self._balance -= amount #takes away amount from balance
        return self._balance #returns balance
    
    def get_balance(self,pin): #creates get balance method with two parameters; self and pin
        if pin != self._pin: #if user enters wrong pin
            print("Wrong pin. Try  Again") 
        return self._balance #returns current balance
    
    def change_pin(self,old_pin,new_pin): #creates change pin method
        if old_pin != self._pin: #if user enters wrong old ppin when prompted
            print("Wrong Pin")
            self._pin = new_pin #set pin equal to enw pin user enters
    
def main(): #main method to call instances
        
    choice = input("Would you like to open account one or two (press 1 or 2): ")
    if choice == 1: #if user chooses account 1
        account = BankAccount(8493) #call one instance of bank account class and set equal to account variable

    elif choice == 2:#if user chooses account 2
        account = BankAccount(8820)#call another instance of bank account class and set equal to account variable

    print("Choose one of the options below: ")
    print("Press 1 to deposit money")
    print("Press 2 to withdraw money")
    print("Press 3 to check balance")
    print("Press 4 to change pin")
    action = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

    if action == 1: #if user chooses 1
        pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")) #get value for pin parameter
        amount = float(input("Enter amount: ")) #get amount for amount paraneter
        print("Current balance is: ", account.deposit(pin,amount)) #accesses the deposit method using dot notation
        return

    elif action == 2: #if user chooses 2
        pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")) #get value for pin parameter
        amount = float(input("Enter amount: "))#get amount for amount paraneter
        print("Current balance is: ", account.withdraw(pin,amount))#accesses the withdraw method using dot notation
        return

    elif action == 3: #if user chooses 3
        pin = int(input("Enter your pin: ")) #get value for pin parameter
        print("Balance is: ", account.get_balance(pin))#accesses the get balance method using dot notation

    elif action == 4: #if user chooses 4
        old_pin = int(input("Enter your old pin: ")) #prompts user to enter pin
        new_pin = int(input("Enter new pin: ")) #prompts user to enter new pin
        account.change_pin(pin,new_pin) #accesses the get change pin method using dot notation
            
main() #calls main function
```

Comment: Did you indent your class?

Comment: I believe you meant `account._pin`, not `pin` in your main function?

Answer (score 0):

The value received from in-built input function is string and not integer. You need to compare string in the if and elif conditions and not integer so that the account variable is initialized.

```
choice = input("Would you like to open account one or two (press 1 or 2): ")
if choice == '1': #if user chooses account 1
    account = BankAccount(8493) #call one instance of bank account class and set equal to account variable

elif choice == '2':#if user chooses account 2
    account = BankAccount(8820)#call another instance of bank account class and set equal to account variable
```

Comment: This is a valid observation but does not answer the question.

Comment: (@code)  The code is working fine with the changes I suggested. Is it throwing error for you? If yes, could you please share the error with me?